# Are TIPC and distributed erlang related?

Tags: erlang, tipc

I was browsing the wikipedia page on TIPC (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIPC) and noticed that the addressing scheme used is similar to Distributed Erlang's pid addresses, when you display it on a different node. Just wondering, since both efforts were developed at Ericsson. There is also some form of periodic ping (heartbeat) mechanism to tell whether the other process is up or not, similar to TIPC.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct relation, -at least no such relation was ever brought to my attention by the Erlang developers. 
But knowing that they were once sitting at an adjacent floor to me in the same building, and there was some information sharing between us, I would be surprised if this is purely coincidental ;) Just for the record, the TIPC addressing scheme is several years older than Distributed Erlang.